# Ошибка парсинга emoji в XML

Tags: c++, qt, boost, xmlparser

Есть следующий код по замене emoji:

```
message = message.replace(":)", u8"\U0001F601");
```

В `qt` отображается все хорошо. Показывается картинка с emoji. Далее сообщение отправляется на сервер для хранения и тут возникают проблемы. Работа с сервером идет через библиотеку `boost`. Перед тем как попасть на сервер сообщение перекодируется:

```
std::wstring newmsg= message.toStdWString().c_str();
std::string msg = boost::to_utf8(newmsg);
```

Далее `msg` загоняется в XML и отправляется на сервер. И XML выдает ошикбку парсинга.

Так же пробовался вариант:

```
auto a = message.toUtf8().replace(":)", u8"\U0001F601");
addMessage(QString::fromUtf8(a));
```

и

```
message = message.replace(":)", QString::fromUtf8(u8"\U0001F601"));
```

Что можно сделать?

P.S. Система Win 10. Сообщение проходит проверку на escape симфолы.

Comment: У Вас есть описание ошибки, которая происходит при парсинге?

Comment: Непонятно, зачем конвертировать в wchar и сразу обратно?

Comment: К сожалению нет. Но точно знаю что на байты не ругается.

Comment: 'Непонятно, зачем конвертировать в wchar и сразу обратно?' - конвертация в utf8 происходит в библиотеке. Исторически так сложилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPD: https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/issues/395

Я не уверен, что ошибка именно здесь, но обратите внимание:

`boost::to_utf8(newmsg)`,

где `newmsg` имеет тип `std::wstring`

А вот та самая ф-ия из Boost'a:

```
template <typename Char, typename Traits, typename Allocator>
        inline utf8_string 
        to_utf8(std::basic_string<Char, Traits, Allocator> const& str)
        {
            // always store as UTF8
            utf8_string result;
            typedef std::back_insert_iterator<utf8_string> insert_iter;
            insert_iter out_iter(result);
            utf8_output_iterator<insert_iter> utf8_iter(out_iter);
            typedef typename make_unsigned<Char>::type UChar;
            BOOST_FOREACH(Char ch, str)
            {
                *utf8_iter++ = (UChar)ch;
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Где `utf8_string` - это std::string.

Так вот, меня смущает вот эта строка:

```
*utf8_iter++ = (UChar)ch;
```

За utf8_iter прячется char, а справа - wchar_t (причем какой-то производный тип, т.к. использовался `make_unsigned`.

Comment: @Madisson, обновил, проверьте, может Ваш баг с этим багом связан.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую!

Comment: @Madisson, рад помочь!

Comment: @Madisson, если вопрос еще актуален для Вас - чекните issue (обновлено).

Comment: Да, проблема была именно с 'std::wstring'. Заменил на 'std::string' - все заработало.